# Is there an API for sending Youtube links to the Youtube applications on Tivo/Smart TVs?

Tags: youtube-api, smart-tv, tivo

I'm having trouble finding documentation on Youtube's developer website whether there is an API for "Youtube for Devices" to send videos to set top boxes like the newer Tivos and similar players.

There is a feature in the Android app that allows a Youtube video to be played via the Tivo when you hit a button, similar to Chromecast.

I thought it might share an API with Chromecast in some way, but I tried the Chromecast extension on Google Chrome for Windows and it failed to detect the Tivo.

Is there an API for this, or is it a proprietary feature of the Youtube app?